# Different ways to get value from hash

Tags: ruby

Why are there different ways to get a value from a hash?

```
h = {"one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3}

puts h[:one] # prints nothing
puts h['one'] # prints 1
puts h["one"] # prints 1
```

and

```
h = Hash.new
h[:one] = 1
h[:two] = 2
h[:three] = 3

puts h[:one] # prints 1
puts h['one'] # prints nothing
puts h["one"] # prints nothing
```

and

```
h = Hash.new
h["one"] = 1
h["two"] = 2
h["three"] = 3

puts h[:one] # prints nothing
puts h['one'] # prints 1
puts h["one"] # prints 1
```

Usually, single quotes and double quotes have the same behavior, but colon is different from them. Is there any explanation?

**Edit**

So, can we consider that the hash from `Activerecord` always has string key?

e.g i have `users` table with column `user_name`.

```
user = User.find_by_id(123) 
user_name = user[:user_name] # get nothing
user_name = user["user_name"] # get correct user_name
```

Comment: A value starting with a colon in Ruby is called a symbol.

Comment: They are not different ways of calling. You are calling in the same way with different keys. As a value in a hash is connected to a certain key, you get different results when you call with different keys.

Comment: so, can we consider that the hash from activerecord always has string key?

Comment: because you checked and it doesn't respond to column style key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html):

```
h = {"one" => 1, "two" => 2, "three" => 3}.with_indifferent_access
```

Because symbol (that how calls `:one`) and string are different Classes. [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Symbol.html) docs.

**Updated**:

For me `ActiveRecord` object array of attributes work with indifferent access (`'name'` and `:name`). *But in your case*, **yes** the attributes array has string keys. Also usually we call them as properties: `user.name` (i guess you are aware of this).

Perhaps you have some older version of Rails, or you don't use Rails ActiveRecord, it maybe Sequel or something.

Comment: sorry incomplete question.
after using .attributes function, i receive hash obj. thanks for answer.